# How to move onto the next item in a list

Tags: c#, winforms

So as part of my training I have to create a program which utilizes the Xbox Api. It works so that the user searches for a Gamer tag and it brings up all of that users recently uploaded game clips. You can then select a clip and it will play within the Windows Media Player control I added.

Now I am trying to set it to auto play the next video. How would I fill out the following method to autoplay the next item in the list keeping in mind that it is not looping through all the videos in the list, just from where the user selects from.

```
private void wmpClip_PlayStateChange(object sender,
                                     AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEvent e)
{
    if (wmpClip.playState == WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsMediaEnded)
    {
        //play next video in list
    }
}
```

So the following code is part of the search method when searching for clips:

```
foreach (var video in videos)
            {
                ctrlSearchResults searchResult = new ctrlSearchResults();
                searchResult.SetDetails(video);
                flpSearchResults.Controls.Add(searchResult);
                searchResult.OnVideoSelected += SearchResult_OnVideoSelected;
                //Limit to save api requests
                if (flpSearchResults.Controls.Count == 3)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Then when the user clicks on a video from the list on the Flow Layout Panel, the following code is run:

```
private void SearchResult_OnVideoSelected(Video obj)
        {
            wmpClip.Visible = true;
            wmpClip.URL = obj.gameClipUris[0].uri;
            pnlVideoInfo.Visible = true;
            lblClipName.Visible = true;
            lblActualLength.Text = obj.durationInSeconds.ToString();
            lblActualSize.Text = (obj.gameClipUris[0].fileSize / 1024 / 1024).ToString() + "mb";
            lblActualDate.Text = obj.datePublished.ToString();
            lblActualGame.Text = obj.titleName;
            lblActualViews.Text = obj.views.ToString();
            lblActualRating.Text = obj.rating.ToString();
            lblActualLikes.Text = obj.likeCount.ToString();
            lblClipName.Text = obj.clipName;

            GamerCard gamer = _clipsApi.GetGamerCardByXUID(obj.xuid.ToString());
            pnlGamerInfo.Visible = true;
            pbGamerPic.Load(gamer.gamerpicLargeSslImagePath);
            lblGamerTag.Text = gamer.gamertag;
            lblGamerScore.Text = gamer.gamerscore.ToString();
            lblActualLocation.Text = gamer.location;
            txtBio.Text = gamer.bio;
        }
```

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Can you post some more code? What is the type of wmpClip?

Comment: @EyIM I have added more code

Comment: What is the type of flpSearchResults? Is it a class member?

Answer (score 1):

You should work on your [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns): divide your big problem into smaller problems, and invent for every smaller problem a separate fairly independent solution. This makes the implementations easier to understand, easier to reust, test, change etc.

So let's separate your concerns!

Apparently you have something to fetch all your videos as a sequence:

```
IEnumerable<Video> GetAllVideos() {...}
```

How this is implemented is up to you. I assume you have no duplicates in this: every Video is either selected or not selected, you can not have the same video selected as well as non-selected.

Let's create a collection class for videos where you can select and unselect videos.
In fact: let's make it reusable: a generic collection class that contains objects that
can be selected and unselected:

```
public SelectableCollection<T>
    // only if desired
    : IReadonlyCollection<T>, IReadonlyList<T>, IEnumerable<T>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<T, bool> allItems;

    public SelectableCollection() : this(Enumerable.Empty<T>()) {}

    public SelectableCollection(IEnumerable<T> collection) : this (collection, null) {}

    public SelectableCollection(IEnumerable<T> source, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = null)
    {
        // TODO: check source not null
        if (comparer == null) comparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;

         // initially nothing selected:
        this.AllItems = source.ToDictionary(video => video, false, comparer);
    }
```

Select and Unselect:

```
bool IsSelected(T item)
{
    // TODO: decide what if item does not exist
    return this.allItems[item];
}

bool Select(T item)
{
    // TODO: decide what if item does not exist
    this.allItems[item] = true;
}

bool UnSelect(T item)
{
    // TODO: decide what if item does not exist
    this.allItems[item] = false;
}

IEnumerable<T> SelectedItems => this.allItems
    // Key is T, Value is boolean Selected
    .Where(keyValuePair => keyValuePair.Value)
    .Select(keyValuePair => keyValuePair.Key);
```

TODO: implement IReadOnlyCollection, etc. Use this.allItems.Keys to get all items.

Your forms class:

```
private SelectableCollection<Video> videos = new SelectableCollection(this.GetAllVideos());
```

Select and Unselect:

```
bool IsSelected(Video video)
{
    return this.videos.IsSelected(video);
}

bool Select(Video video)
{
    this.videos.Select(video);
}

bool UnSelect(Video video)
{
    this.videos.UnSelect(video);
}

IEnumerable<Video> SelectedVideos => this.videos.SelectedItems;
```

Start / Stop / Continue playing Videos:

```
class VideoPlayer
{
    private List<Video> VideosToPlay {get; set;}
    private int IndexNextVideoToPlay {get; set;}

    void StartPlayingVideos(IEnumerable<Video> videos)
    {
        this.VideosToPlay = this.SelectedVideos.ToList();
        this.IndexNextVideoToPlay = 0;
    }

    private void PlayNextVideo()
    {
        if (this.IndexNextVideoToPlay < this.VideosToPlay.Count)
        {
            this.Play(this.VideosToPlay[this.IndexNextVideoToPlay];
            ++this.IndexNextVideoToPlay;
        }
    }
}
```

Examples:

```
private void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // user finished selecting videos in the listbox. Mark them as selected
     IEnumerable<Video> selectedVideos = this.listBox1.SelectedItems.Cast<Video>();

     // TODO: select all selectedVideos; Unselect all not-selected videos.         
}

private void OnVideoFinished(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.VideoPlayer.PlayNextVideo();
}
```

Conclusion: divide your problem into small sub problems. Don't hesitate to create a class that solves your sub problem. Usually these classes will only have one small task and barely depend on other classes. Hence your class will be easy to understande, easy to create, easy to reuse, easy to test and maintain.